# GWT:how to make tabPanel to 100% height

Tags: gwt

I am using TabPanel in my GWt application

```
              <g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="center">
        <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barUnit="PX"
            barHeight="40" width="100%;">
            <g:tab>
                <g:header>
                    DashBoard
                </g:header>
              </ g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

using this for my tabpanel height

```
          .gwt-TabLayoutPanel {
           min-height:500px;
             }
```

its working fine , BUT i want this height to be 100%, But when I make it to 100% ,The whole TabPanel disappears ,

Any solution for that ..coz when my stuff hights increase , the lower are start cutting off ..

thanks

Comment: it will be easy to provide solution if you post code, so we can easily how exactly you want it to be appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with 100% height is it will be 1px if the parent container does not have a height set.

You might find the following article intresting as a possible workarround.
http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Comment: You are correct, mine only explains why his tabpanel disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Put your TabLayoutPanel in a LayoutPanel or any other panel that provides size to its children. For example, if you put your panel directly into the RootLayoutPanel, it will take 100% of the screen automatically, and it will resize with the browser window.