# GWT: CellTable inside FlowPanel inside TabPanel

Tags: gwt, size, tabpanel, celltable, flowpanel

I have a CellTable widget (item that extends Composite and has a CellTable + Pager via UiBinder), which is inside a FlowPanel, which is the contents of a tab for a TabPanel.

I've set the height and width programmatically (for now) on all so that:
CellTable : 600px x 500px
FlowPanel : 650px x 550px
TabPanel : 700px x 600px

When the page renders I can check the HTML to see that my CellTable has content and width + height set fine, so do all the other components but for some reason I can't see the table. Only an empty tab panel. Any ideas why or how I can size my components correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the height of the tab panel.

Refer the following links

[TabLayoutPanel not showing widgets only Tab items are visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738904/tablayoutpanel-not-showing-widgets-only-tab-items-are-visible/13739312#13739312)

[GWT:how to make tabPanel to 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669748/gwthow-to-make-tabpanel-to-100-height).